# Multiple row INSERT from a single SELECT result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am inserting multiple rows into a table, using the result from a subquery :

```
INSERT INTO `doc-file` (docId, fileId) VALUES
    ((SELECT id FROM documents WHERE slug = :slug LIMIT 1), :file1),
    ((SELECT id FROM documents WHERE slug = :slug LIMIT 1), :file2),
    ((SELECT id FROM documents WHERE slug = :slug LIMIT 1), :file3),
```

The result from the subquery would be the same for every row I want to insert, so it really only needs to be run once. Written like this, wouldn't the subquery be run multiple times? Is there a way to run this subquery only once, and still reuse its result into multiple rows ?

Comment: Check the explain plan and measure it, if it's really a problem. Chances are that: a) Optimizer optimizes this and effectively execute the query only once. b) Even with different parameters, optimizer would probably turn it into a single query c) Any other solution will be at least as slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable:

```
set @value = (SELECT id FROM documents WHERE slug = :slug LIMIT 1);
INSERT INTO `doc-file` (docId, fileId) VALUES
    (@value, :file1),
    (@value, :file2),
    (@value, :file3),
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised this is the first time I ever see someone mentionning variables in SQL; I was almost going to believe they didn't exist. 
Is there a reason people would avoir using them ?

Comment: They do exist and they are very useful but rarely used outside of functions, stored procedures and triggers as all developers try to keep things simple. In your case a variable solves easily a problem, so why not?

Answer (score 0):

you could unique files in separate temp table and join it on condition like 1=1
If you dont want to maintain separate table populate distinct values in Subquery
so you will have separate tables, let says fileNames
fileNames:
file1
file2
file3

```
  INSERT INTO `doc-file` (docId, fileId) VALUES
        ( select a.id,f.fileID 
        (SELECT id FROM documents WHERE slug = :slug LIMIT 1) a 
        inner join filenames f on 1=1 
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cross join the subquery and another subquery getting the files by `UNION ALL`ing `FROM`-less `SELECT`s.

```
INSERT INTO `doc-file`
            (docId,
             fileId)
            SELECT x.id,
                   y.file
                   FROM (SELECT id
                                FROM documents
                                WHERE slug = :slug
                                LIMIT 1) x
                        CROSS JOIN (SELECT :file1 file
                                    UNION ALL
                                    SELECT :file2 file
                                    UNION ALL
                                    SELECT :file3 file) y;
```